# MMA845X accelerometer mapped at 1C

Tags: i2c, sensor

I have a MMA845X accelerometer mapped at 1C:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1c -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I use this python script to get some results

```
import smbus
DEVICE_ADDRESS = 0x1c
MMA8451_REG_WHOAMI = 0x0D
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
ret = bus.read_byte_data(DEVICE_ADDRESS, MMA8451_REG_WHOAMI)
print ret
```

but I get always 0.

After a small research I find out that this sensor require repeated start and that repeated start is not available for Raspberry Pi.

How do I make it work?

Comment: What model Pi are you using? what Distro are you using and what version is it?

Comment: Raspberry Pi B 2 , Raspbian Jessie 8

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to get repeated starts to work with the following command.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "Y" >/sys/module/i2c_bcm2708/parameters/combined'
```

Try that and see if your script works.

Comment: Now I get constantlly 42

Comment: I think it might be a problem with `MMA8451_REG_WHOAMI = 0x0D` , I don't know what this address is.

Comment: 0x0d (decimal 13) is the correct register address.  It should return 0x1a (26). pigpio will let you bit bang repeated starts using [bb_i2c_zip](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bb_i2c_zip).  Depends on how far your programming skills have developed.

Comment: I get 0x2a What does that mean?

Comment: I have no idea apart from it isn't the expected documented value.

Answer (score 0):

you are not sending the correct data.
if you are looking for a complete code you can get here.
[MMA845X Python code](https://www.controleverything.com/content/Accelorometer?sku=MMA8452Q_I2CS)

go to resources tab you will find the code.

make sure your sensor is connected correctly.